# ListView not scrolling in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, fragment

I'm trying use a Fragment with ViewPager, but the ListView scroll not work.

This is my code:

```
    public class MeuTreino extends FragmentDrawerModel 
    { //1 editar, 2 novo, 3 remover
        ViewPager Tab;
        MeuTreinoTPA TabAdapter;
        ActionBar actionBar;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.meu_treino);
            getActionBar().setTitle("Meu treino");
            init();
            TabAdapter = new MeuTreinoTPA(getSupportFragmentManager());
            Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager); 
            Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
                    new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                            actionBar = getActionBar();
                            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    }
                    });
            Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                        FragmentTransaction ft) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                        FragmentTransaction ft) {
                    Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                        FragmentTransaction ft) {

                }

            };
            //Add New Tab
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Treinos").setTabListener(tabListener));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Histórico").setTabListener(tabListener));
        }
```

My TreinosFragment class

```
public class TreinosFragment extends Fragment{
    private ArrayList<Treino> treinos; 
    private AdapterTreino adapter;
    private View view;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meu_treino, container, false);
        configurarListaTreino();
        return view;
    }

    private void carregarTreino()
    {
        treinos = Treino.getTreinos(getActivity());
        adapter = new AdapterTreino(getActivity(), treinos);
        ListView ltDados = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.lvTreinos);
        configurarListaTreino();
        ltDados.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

My XML's

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCriarTreino"
            style="@style/BotaoTabPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:onClick="criarTreino"
            android:text="NOVO TREINO" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

the 2nd XML

```
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvHistoricoTreino"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvTreinos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

How you can see, I have a FragmentActivity, two fragments with a ListView each, in the Layout of fragmentActivity I have only a bottom button.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why you didnt add a scroll view in your xml file??

Comment: But I have a button in button, it doesn't matter? Which xml?

Comment: What do you mean by button in button?

Comment: You should wrap your list view in a scroll view to make it scroll able

Comment: Usually a ListView not work inside scrollview layout.